# Ways of accessing nested map values in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am currently using the two following blocks of code to access nested values in ClojureScript:

```clj
  (def response (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/quote]))
  (def body (:body @response))
  (def value (:value body))
  (println value)
```

```clj
  (def result (-> @(re-frame/subscribe [::subs/quote]) :body :value))
  (println result)
```

```clj
 (def lol (get-in @(re-frame/subscribe [::subs/quote]) [:body :value]))
 (println lol)
```

Are there any better / more succinct ways of doing this?

Comment: I usually have a simple `(defn sub [s] @(re-frame/subscribe [s]))` that I use in my components.
This removes some of the visual noise:
`(get-in (sub ::subs/quote) [:body :value])`

Comment: For retrieving multiple keys I like nested destructuring:

`(let [{{:keys [value another-key]} :body} @(re-frame/subscribe [::subs/quote]])
  [value another-key])`

So destructure to get the `body` and bind the values of the keys from the body to `value` and `another-key`.

Comment: Good shouts both 

Answer (score 2):

Keys can be used as operators to retrieve its value like so:

```clj
(def lol (:value (:body @(re-frame/subscribe [::subs/quote]))))
(println lol)
```

However, I prefer the verbose way using a function as `get-in`